# Bash script telnet connection + for loop

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to make bash script that connects via telnet and executes multiple commands using for loop.

Here is what i've tried:

```
{echo "username"; sleep 1; echo "password";  for host in {`cat hosts`}; do echo "show configuration | display set | match $host";done; sleep 15; } | telnet <ip>
```

Comment: You might want to look into ssh. That will let you connect to the remote host securely without your password being on the commandline.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: My question is what i am doing wrong cause it does not execute , the commands properly , for example the first host which is trying to loog for looks like this {12.168.3.3} and it should be 12.168.3.3 withouth the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The additional brackets are because of

```
for host in {`cat hosts`} ; do
```

you don't need them

```
for host in `cat hosts` ; do
```

or

```
for host in $(hosts) ; do
```

But as stated in the comments take a look at SSH (sending the credentials in clear text and storing them in a script is not the best idea)

```
for host in $(cat hosts) ; do
    ssh user@$host "show configuration | display set | match $host"
done
```

Comment: Ok i've tried with ssh but stil didnt work :

#!/bin/bash
ssh user@192.168.3.3 <<'ENDSSH'
for hosts in {`cat hosts`};do "show configuration | display set | match $hosts" ; done
ENDSSH

Comment: @user2642601 Why the brackets? Which shell are you using?